# Can I configure Windows 10 to create smaller screenshots?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

If I use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>, I can create a screenshot that will be stored in png format. I just find the file size way too large (8 MB on a dual monitor setup at 1920x1080).

I want to keep them below 2 MB.

Can I configure the standard Windows tool to create smaller file sizes?

I know I could use different tools to shrink the image files, yet this is not the scope of this question. I want to know if it is possible within the Win 10 toolset or if I just have to deal with.

Comment: Do you actually need both displays to be captured? If not, using the snipping tool to select the specific area you want to capture and saving it as a .jpg should reduce the file size quite a bit

Comment: Import into a photo program and save as jpeg.

Comment: @Moab As stated, I know I can do that. That is not the question.

Comment: @benjaminS One monitor still boils down to 4MB, so no solution.

Comment: Screenshots are stored in the clipboard and have to be imported into some kind of software.

Comment: I want to know too...